# Copy dataframe rows and add ID; ID stored in list with variable number of columns

Tags: r, tidyverse, data-cleaning

I have a list of integer vectors I want to use to expand my dataframe. Each vector inside this list corresponds to every row of my dataframe, in order.

For each of these vectors inside my list, I want to duplicate the corresponding row in my dataframe, creating as many of these rows as there are items in the vector. I then want to add a column to these duplicate rows containing the years the vector holds. 
(Example code / data below)

How would I do this using dplyr or most simply/clearly?

```
evlist <- list("75931" = c(2018, 2018, 2017), "75932" =  c(2003

# $`75931`
# [1] 2018 2018 2017
# 
# $`75932`
# [1] 2003

id_df <- data.frame(gid = c(183253, 183254, 183255, 183256))
  evlist <- list("75931" = c(2018, 2018, 2017),
                 "75932" =  c(2003, NA, NA))
# gid
# 1 183253
# 2 183254
# 3 183255
# 4 183256

# Goal DataFrame:
goal <- data.frame(gid = c(183253, 183253, 183253, 183254, 183255, 183256), 
                   year = c(2018, 2018, 2017, 2003, NA, NA))

#     gid year
# 1 183253 2018
# 2 183253 2018
# 3 183253 2017
# 4 183254 2003
# 5 183255   NA
# 6 183256   NA
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can approach this with [tidyverse](/questions/tagged/tidyverse) verbs to reshape your `evlist` and `left_join` back to your data frame with an index for row matching.

```
library(tibble)
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)

evlist <- list(
  "75931" = c(2018, 2018, 2017),
  "75932" =  c(2003)
)

id_df <- tibble(
  gid = c(183253, 183254, 183255, 183256)
)

id_df %>%
  rowid_to_column %>%                  # add index for matching
  left_join(
    evlist %>%
      t %>%                            # using transpose to pivot rows~columns
      as_tibble %>%                    # recast into a data frame for subsequent steps
      gather(rowid, year) %>%          # use gather to nest the year values
      mutate(rowid = row_number()) %>% # transform the "names" of evlist to the index
      unnest,                          # flatten the new evlist
    by = "rowid"
  ) %>%
  select(-rowid)                       # drop the index now that it served its purpose

# # A tibble: 6 x 2
#      gid  year
#    <dbl> <dbl>
# 1 183253  2018
# 2 183253  2018
# 3 183253  2017
# 4 183254  2003
# 5 183255    NA
# 6 183256    NA
```

Comment: Thanks so much. Could you say a little more on how you manipulated `evlist` (or point me to a reference that goes into these niche [tag:tidyverse] manipulations)? I see you took the list of vectors and called `t()` for transpose, which I believe converted it to a matrix of lists before you created what I think is a list-column?

Comment: @shiba, please see my edit providing commentary on the steps. You can also run just a section in your IDE to look at the output to see how things change based on elements of the *pipe* chain (*i.e.* `evlist %>% t %>% as_tibble %>% gather(rowid, year)`).